# Draw an object on an OpenCV image using OpenGL

Tags: opencv, opengl, augmented-reality

I have been trying to draw a 3D cube using opengl over a camera stream from opencv but unsuccessful. Added setOpenGlDrawCallback but it's not overlaying the opengl image onto opencv image. Following is the code.

**trackingmanager.h** is the header file of class which takes care of devices/frames/etc.
**frameprocessor.h** is the header file of class used to do some processing on the frame obtained from the camera.

The namedWindow is being initialized in **trackingmanager.cpp** by,

> namedWindow(wnd_name, WINDOW_OPENGL);

I can see the opengl image being drawn to the same window if I do not render the opencv fram to this window. (Comment out tm->renderFrame()).

Also, I get to see following messages on run,

> 1] init done 
>   2] Opengl support available

```
#include <iostream>
#include "trackingmanager.h"
#include "frameprocessor.h"
#include <GL/glut.h>

using namespace std;
static void renderObject(void *param);
vector<vector<Point> > square;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    TrackingManager *tm = new TrackingManager();
    FrameProcessor *processor = new FrameProcessor();
    setOpenGlContext(tm->wnd_name);
    setOpenGlDrawCallback(tm->wnd_name, renderObject, NULL);

    while(tm->getFrame()){
        square = processor->process(&tm->frame);
        tm->renderFrame();
        updateWindow(tm->wnd_name);

        int key = waitKey(10);
        if(key == 27){
            tm->releaseCamera();
            break;
        }
    }
    setOpenGlDrawCallback(tm->wnd_name, NULL, NULL);
    return 0;
}

static void renderObject(void* param)
{
     glLoadIdentity();
     glClearColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
     glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
     glColor3f (1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
     glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
     glTranslated(0.0, 0.0, -1.0);

     glRotatef( 55, 1, 0, 0 );
     glRotatef( 45, 0, 1, 0 );
     glRotatef( 0, 0, 0, 1 );

     static const int coords[6][4][3] = {
        { { +1, -1, -1 }, { -1, -1, -1 }, { -1, +1, -1 }, { +1, +1, -1 }   },
        { { +1, +1, -1 }, { -1, +1, -1 }, { -1, +1, +1 }, { +1, +1, +1 }   },
        { { +1, -1, +1 }, { +1, -1, -1 }, { +1, +1, -1 }, { +1, +1, +1 } },
         { { -1, -1, -1 }, { -1, -1, +1 }, { -1, +1, +1 }, { -1, +1, -1 } },
        { { +1, -1, +1 }, { -1, -1, +1 }, { -1, -1, -1 }, { +1, -1, -1 } },
        { { -1, -1, +1 }, { +1, -1, +1 }, { +1, +1, +1 }, { -1, +1, +1 } }
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
         glColor3ub( i*20, 100+i*10, i*42 );
         glBegin(GL_QUADS);
         for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
              glVertex3d(0.2 * coords[i][j][0], 0.2 * coords[i][j][1], 0.2 * coords[i][j][2]);
          }
          glEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: you need a namedWindow with CV_WINDOW_OPENGL flag, too. also `cerr << cv::getBuildInformation();` to see, if opengl support was compiled in or not.

Comment: @berak: Already have it initialized via trackingmanager. That wnd_name thing is being used to initialize it. I can see the opengl image being drawn to the same window if I do not render the opencv fram to this window.

Comment: also, you can *either* render an image *or* a 3d scene. it won't automatially overlay things (if you expected that)

Comment: @berak : Ok. Any way they could be combined? Or I would say, how shall I combine them?

Comment: hmm. render an additional groundplane, with your videostream as texture ?  (helpful edits, btw)

Comment: most demos simply go the other way, draw the videoimage(2d), and just do your own projection for the cube

Comment: Yes, opencv frame in background and the opengl object as foreground. You may assume this is the first time I am using OpenGL, so am not familiar with its terminologies.

Comment: Have you looked at Viz3d in the more recent OpenCV versions?  (It's in the pre-release 3.0 and a few 2.4 versions)   It doesn't have a lot of features but it might be all you need and avoid issues with trying to integrate raw opengl or other libraries.

Comment: @LucasW : Didn't know about it. Just had a quick look into it. Doesn't seem like it can solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with moving over to python, there is a library called scikit-surgeryvtk available through pip. This library allows you to easily overlay any arbitrary object onto your opencv background. The library implements Visual ToolKit (VTK) to do all of the 3D heavy lifting. This library is a lot higher level (easier to work with) than  openGL.